# callback causing memory leak

Tags: javascript

```
Model.GetData(function (args,jsonData) {
    RenderData(jsonData);
});
```

I am passing a callback to my model class,

```
var Model = (function () {
    function GetData(args,callback) {
       // do all math works. 

       var HTTPClient;

       HTTPClient.onload = function () {
           callback(this.responseText);
       };
    }

})();
```

Will my callback cause memory leak in my view page.

Comment: Please show us working code. The IEFE from above returns `undefined`, so `Model.GetData` will not cause a memory leak but a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The `onload` global variable will store a reference to your function, which is in the same scope as your `args` and `callback`.

Comment: @theJava - Well, in your current form, it's *not* leaking.

Comment: Can you post the old, leaky version of the code for educational purposes?

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira: I'd guess it actually does not leak